Google play RTDN subscription renewals - how to determine whether introductory pricing was used?
I am testing out introductory pricing for a subscription in google play.   It is set up so that the first three months are $2.99, and after that the standard price of $9.99 applies.
The problem I am having is understanding what price was actually paid when I receive the RTDN webhook.    The webhook gives me a purchaseToken which I use to pull information on the subscription purchase.   The information returned looks like this:
[
  {
    "startTimeMillis": "1716989904253",
    "expiryTimeMillis": "1716990447152",
    "autoRenewing": true,
    "priceCurrencyCode": "USD",
    "priceAmountMicros": "9990000",
    "countryCode": "UY",
    "developerPayload": "",
    "paymentState": 1,
    "orderId": "GPA.3388-7820-5338-54114..0",
    "purchaseType": 0,
    "acknowledgementState": 1,
    "introductoryPriceInfo": {
      "introductoryPriceCurrencyCode": "USD",
      "introductoryPriceAmountMicros": "2990000",
      "introductoryPricePeriod": "PT5M",
      "introductoryPriceCycles": 3
    },
    "kind": "androidpublisher#subscriptionPurchase",
    "obfuscatedExternalAccountId": "b2b4deff32f6545e3722a29fc946fac274d75e30"
  }
]

At first glance, it has everything needed.  It has the introductory price, the standard price, and all the details about how the introductory pricing works.    The problem I'm having is the response looks pretty much exactly the same for the first renewal (where the price is still $2.99) as it does for the 3rd renewal (where the price changes to $9.99).
In both cases the priceAmountMicros is 9990000 and the introductoryPriceInfo. introductoryPriceAmountMicros is 2990000.   But the response itself doesn't tell me which price was used.
I considered calculating whether the user is in the introductory period by using the introductoryPricePeriod and introductoryPriceCycles, but this information is also missing the "originalStartTime" so that doesn't seem possible either.
How can I determine what the price was for a given purchase?

I'm struggling with the same issue. That looks like a subscriptions result. As of 2022, there is a new subscriptionsv2 API which changes this object. One of the changes is the addition of a lineItems. I haven't had a chance to see if that might help. But my word this is so much more complicated that Apple's notifications!
